# How to avoid TListView to fire a OnSelectItem event (c++ Embarcadero)

Tags: c++, tlistview

I'm currently working with TListView on Embarcadero C++, with objects that could potentially have several thousands of items.
I want to set up a CTRL+A feature, so that all the items would be selected at once. I managed in doing it, however, when using myListView->SelectAll();, it fires a OnSelectItem event for each item (!!!), which can take a huge amount of time. 
I tried BeginUpdate/EndUpdate, Enabled = false with no result at all - i.e. OnSelectItem is triggered for each item.
Even if I set a variable to achieve an immediate return from the OnSelectItem event, it takes way too much time.

Is there a simple solution to avoid thousands of events triggered when SelectAll() is called ?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Please try commenting out your OnSelectItem() body and check if it still takes an unacceptable time

Comment: So what ? I will need the OnSelectItem again for some other features... Ok, I will try...

Comment: Ok, I tried. We get from 18 sec (OnSelectItem is handled, tests one boolean and returns) to 6 sec (no OnSelectItem handled) for 38k items count.

Comment: I tried also, in the same conditions, (i.e. with the same list of items) to set the OnSelectItem to NULL, then SelectAll then reset OnSelectItem to its previous value, and it does not change the execution time at all for the SelectAll.

Answer (score 0):

It would not surprise me if that's not possible, but I'm wondering why it takes so much time the calls to OnSelectItem for less than 100 000 items... perhaps you just need to improve the OnSelectItem management performance, e.g. just return from them if you are in the middle of a SelectAll

**Added after some comments:**

yeah, the TListView is not meant to work with so many items, I don't see any user scrolling that much lines, anyway, it seems it will be a lot faster if you do it in another thread [like they recommend in this Embarcadero article](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/technical-articles/162-programming/15287-adding-way-too-many-items-to-a-tlistview)

Comment: Already did that: The OnSelectItem procedure just tests a boolean then returns.

Comment: Ok, I think I found a way to speed that up: when I select the first item, then hit CTRL+MAJ+END on the keyboard, all the items are selected in a wink. Now, I have to find out how to send a keystroke on a control, which seems to be the next question I'll ask, it seems I cannot find any valuable answer. Stay tuned!

Comment: And when you use that shortcut your OnSelectItem method gets called?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be called, but it is ok in my app whether it calls it or not, as something happens only when one item is selected.